# Phpstorm-Symfony2 Errors after format code

Tags: php, symfony, phpstorm

I installed Phpstorm yesterday to try it with my symfony2 projet. I tried thé "format code" option.... But now i have lors of Errors like

```
 ReflectionException in AddConsoleCommandPass.php line 40:

Class

SensioLabs\Security\Command\SecurityCheckerCommand

does not exist
```

How can i fix it please?
Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the reformat on your code, no the Symfony vendors files. Try it for example in a controller or in an entity file. To configure PHPStorm to use the [Symfony2 coding standards](http://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/code/standards.html) check out [this tutorial](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PHP+Code+Sniffer+with+Symfony2+Coding+Standards+Integration+in+PhpStorm+-+Symfony+Development+using+PhpStorm). More infos [here to use PHPStorm with Symfony2](http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2014/08/symfony-development-using-phpstorm/).

Comment: PHPStorms takes care of Symfony. In settings > Editor > Code Style > PHP you can select some predefined coding standards. In the list of version 10, there are PEAR, Zend, PSR-1, PSR-2, Drupal, Wordpress and Symfony 2. Enjoy ! ;-)

Comment: Can i cancel m'y first format code or cet back m'y working code?

Comment: @Flushdrew You may use `Local History` functionality to rollback your changes (as long as it is still intact) -- https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Local+History+in+PhpStorm